# How to load multiple yaml files with PyYAML?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a list of yaml files I want to load and return their contents in one single dictionary.

The easiest way would be to iterate through the filenames and load individually with `safe_load`, and then merge the resulting dictionaries.
However,I was wondering if the python yaml library has already a functionality for that. I saw there are methods `load_all` and `safe_load_all`, but they still take only one stream, so I'm not sure if or how I can use those.

Comment: The `load_all` and `safe_load_all` methods will return a list of documents. You could achieve the same thing with multiple files by simply appending each one to a list. If you want a single dictionary, you would need to figure out your merging strategy (are all the input files related? Does it makes *sense* to merge them? In the event of conflicting keys, what should happen?)

Answer (score 3):

This `stream` term is somewhat misleading. For the `PyYaml` library, you can think of it as a string (or a file) containing multiple yaml documents, such as this:

```yaml
field1: foo
field2: bar
---
field1: baz
field2: qux
field3: fred
---
field4: fred
```

To use the `load_all` (or `safe_load_all`) for multiple documents split in multiple files, you will need to concatenate them, in some form. The function `load_all` itself is not able to read multiple files in a folder at once, right out of the box.

Long story short, you have two options:

1. Use a loop or list comprehension to iterate over the files, calling the method `read()`, then using `yaml.load` over them individually
2. Use a loop or list comprehension to iterate over the files and concatenate them in just one string with the format showed above (with documents separated by `\n---\n`), to process it using `yaml.load_all`

If you have a way to start with one single file and multiple documents inside (instead of multiple files), you can use `yaml.load_all` on that file directly.

It is important to notice that `yaml.load_all` returns a `generator` to you. Iterating over this generator brings you a `dictionary` for each document between `---`. You can achieve your *merging* by assigning the first dictionary to a variable and calling the `.update()` method for each of the next dictionaries inside the generator:

```py
gen = yaml.load_all(string)
starting_dict = next(gen)
for d in gen:
    starting_dict.update(d)
```